# What is the mathematical equivalent of an axle?

Tags: soft-question, physics, mathematical-modeling, clifford-algebras

I am talking about axles in machines, on which we can put gears, belts and other devices that help us convert the motion.

So this structure has to have (at least) the following properties:

- **distance** - works like a line, i can 'put' more stuff on it and be able to 'differentiate'(not in a mathematical sense) between them, essentially a $d(x_1, x_2)$ function has to be defined on it
- has *finite* or *infinite* length
- if i were to put a gear on it then the **direction** and the **angular velocity** of the rotation of the gear would be equivalent
- **anticommutativity** of its rotations(2 exist in 3D)
- the 'speed' of **two parallel axes can be compared** by a gear placed on each axle, so that they touch
- the touching point doesn't move at all, but the gears of a touching point have **opposite rotation** and **same angular velocity**
- touching gears **need not** be of same sizes

Of course if you liked to, you could generalize this to any curve.

Initially i thought of the cross-product and normals to a bi-vector. But those don't fulfil all requirements.

**Is there a specific object that describes the motions and properties of a physical axle? (even only as a crude model)**

Comment: There are many aspects of a physical axle that you might want to include or exclude from a mathematical model.  Are rotations of "wheels" at the ends of axles involved (keeping the axle itself fixed)?  Is rotation of the axle itself allowed?  Is there a "differential gear" so that wheels can rotate at different rates?  Etc.  The context of your Question is more important than perhaps you realize.

Comment: Okay, i will try to specify, thank you @hardmath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Screw theory](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screw_theory) seems like what you want, or is at least highly relevant.  I do not know how to apply it to your problem specifically without more details.